# fadeOut() callback completes before fading is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a font-test page that should switch the font of the header and paragraph tags on click. Which works fine but the experience is really jarring so I want to smooth it out with the following path:

> fadeout -> do the font swap -> fade in

But the code runs the font swap first, then the animation.

I have the following code snippet, I am only including the jQuery because it's the root cause of my problem.

```
// Anytime a card is clicked
$('.card').click(function(){
    // Call card by id and switch the fonts
    var id = "#" + this.parentElement.id;
    $(this).fadeOut(900,swapFont(id));
    $(this).fadeIn(500);
    // attach the above to some sort of transition callback

});

// Function to swap the font around so that the header is now the body font and the body font is now the header font
function swapFont(id) {
 // font-swap logic in here which works fine
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently passing the result of the `swapFont()` call, instead you need to point to the function itself.

So this:

```
$(this).fadeOut(900,swapFont(id));
```

is the same as:

```
 var x = swapFont(id);
 $(this).fadeOut(900, x);
```

Easiest way is to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
$(this).fadeOut(900, function() { swapFont(id) });
```

---

**Edit:**

The `fadeIn` will also execute before the `fadeOut` has completed.  You can add a `.delay` or, better, call the `fadeIn` in the callback as per Rory's answer (so I won't repeat here).

Comment: I literrally just did the wrapping method, came back to answer and close but you already posted. I get that it works. But why does it work? Is it because jQuery doesn't recognize the function as a callback?

Comment: It's because you're passing the result of the function - you need to pass the function itself.  It's not the most obvious concept, but quite powerful when you get it.  Used to be called a `function pointer` but in js it's called `function variable`.

Comment: Ah... So calling the name doesn't point to the function it points to it's return value. So in a callback you need a var to return the function or an annoymous function to return the type. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you

Comment: No - calling it with `.fadeOut(900, swapFont)` is the correct way (notice no `()` on swapFont).  As soon as you add `()` you execute immediately.  In this case you also want to pass an id so can't use that format.

Comment: hmmm so passing it as `swapFont` says `fadeOut then do swapFont`. Passing in `swapFont(id)` says `fadeOut with what swapFont returns, since it's nested`?

Comment: passing without bracket says call it as the callback.  Passing with brackets says call it first, then pass the result as the callback (in this case the result is null).

Answer (score 6):

The issue is because the `fadeOut()` animation is (effectively) asynchronous. This means the next statement will be evaluated while the animation is in progress - hence the behaviour you're seeing. To fix this you need to use the callback pattern that the `fadeX()` methods provide.

Also, you're passing the result of the immediate execution of `swapFont()` to the callback, instead of a function reference to run when the event occurs. Try this:

```
$('.card').click(function(){
  var id = "#" + this.parentElement.id;
  $(this).fadeOut(900, function() {
    swapFont(id);
    $(this).fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: This also fixes the issue with passing the result of `swapFont()` (but doesn't mention it).  does now, in the edit :)

Comment: @freedomn-m it does now, and I managed to ninja edit before you commented :D

Comment: By `fadeX()` I mean the `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`, `fadeToggle()` etc methods. The `fadeIn()` has to be inside the callback - that's the point of this answer. Anything *inside* that function occurs *after* the fadeOut animation finishes

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I see what you mean and the above edit explained